# high precision (~200 sig figs) incomplete gamma function callable in C

Tags: python, c, precision

im wondering if anyone knows of any libraries that allow for very high precision (200+ sig figs, preferably just arbitrary) incomplete gamma functions?  So far the only thing i've found is mpmath for python, but I have no idea how I would incorporate that into C code, if that is even possible.

It could be in any language, just so long as I can somehow link it and call it from C.

Cheers

Comment: Many python libraries which which require lots of processing / unusual data types are actually written in C and then wrapped in python. Consider looking at the source for mpmath to check if it's C code. **Edit:** No such luck. Pure Python

Comment: OK, now I'm curious - what are you doing that requires 200 digits? You can get the diameter of the observable universe down to the nanometer in only 36 digits.

Comment: How about [Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic#Libraries)?

Comment: http://www.alglib.net/specialfunctions/incompletegamma.php

Comment: I'm integrating a function :

Integrate[(1/(a^N)) Exp[-0.5*(y^2)/a^2], {a, 0.5, 10}]

which has the difference between two incomplete gamma functions, both of which are 10^200 ish, but are different by around 10^5.  Im using it in a Bayesian log likelihood, where a log difference of 5 makes all the difference.

Comment: I had a look at ALGLIB but i could only see the incomplete function in the non high precision library

Comment: Hmm.  Your best bet may be MPFR plus a standard algorithm, then.

Comment: Can you do the integral directly numerically, rather than expressing it as a difference of incomplete gamma function values?  That would presumably avoid the need for ultra-high precision.

Comment: Will check that out now.. may be a viable option

Comment: Would it be possible to express the integral in a different way that avoids the issue of subtractive cancellation, for example by using the lower incomplete gamma function instead of the upper incomplete gamma function, or vice versa? The motivation for this approach is the way the complementary error function `erfc` is sometimes used in place of the error function `erf` to avoid cancellation. Or maybe there is a 'nice' series expansion that expresses the difference of the two incomplete gamma functions directly? Maple or Mathematica may be able to help find such a series expansion.

Comment: This is now available in MPFR 4.0.0: http://www.mpfr.org/mpfr-current/mpfr.html#index-mpfr_005fgamma_005finc

Answer (score 1):

I think the [GNU MP Bignum library](https://gmplib.org/) is exactly what you're looking for.

You can do things like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <gmp.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    mpz_t a, b, c;
    if (argc&lt3) {
        printf("Please supply two numbers to add.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    mpz_init_set_str (a, argv[1], 10);
    mpz_init_set_str (b, argv[2], 10);
    mpz_add (c, a, b);

    printf("%s + %s => %s\n", argv[1], argv[2], mpz_get_str (NULL, 10, c));
    return 0;
```

Compile with: `gcc -o add_example add_example.c -lgmp -lm`

Comment: Hardly: GMP provides basic arithmetic functions at arbitrary precision.  That's quite a long way from providing an implementation of the incomplete gamma function.

Comment: Sorry. You're right. I forgot about the gamma function ;-)

Comment: I find MPFR (which is based on GMP) to be more accommodating for working with floating point numbers: http://www.mpfr.org/

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative route, you could use a mathematical application that supports running in batch like [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), [Mathematica](http://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/) or [Matlab](http://www.mathworks.nl/products/matlab/).

I tried the following Maxima script:

```
fpprec : 200;
fpprintprec : 200;
bfloat(gamma_incomplete(2,bfloat(2.3)));
```

Running it like this: `maxima -q -b ./incompletegamma.mc run` gives:

```
(%i1) batch("./gamma.mc")

read and interpret file: ./gamma.mc
(%i2) fpprec:200
(%o2)                                 200
(%i3) fpprintprec:1000
(%o3)                                1000
(%i4) bfloat(gamma_incomplete(2,bfloat(2.3)))
(%o4) 3.3085418428525236227076532372691440857133290256546276037973522730841281\
226873248876116604879039570340226922621099906787322361219389317316508680513479\
116358485422369818232009561056364657588558639170139b-1
```

You can use `system()` or `call()` to run the maxima script from a python application like this:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["maxima", "-q -b ./incompletegamma.mc run"])
```